# Can not unlock redisson lock in rabbit listener in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-amqp, redisson

I have the following code block in a rbbit listener in spring boot. I try to get a lock using redisson:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = Const.Rabbit.QUEUE_NAME, concurrency = "1")
    public void consumer(byte[] payload) throws IOException {
        String lockName = "lock-name";
        RLock lock = redissonClient.getLock(lockName);
        try {
            // call a method
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error: {}", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
```

Then I get the following error. It can not release the lock because it is not locked by the current thread. Next, because rabbit message get not acknoledged. rabbit redelivers it infinitely.

```
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'public void consumer(byte[]) throws java.io.IOException' threw exception
.
.
.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: attempt to unlock lock, not locked by current thread by node id: e8289934-2820-42f2-aa3d-30c3f56ce1ac thread-id: 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code snippet you share there is has to be this code yet before `try`:

```
lock.lock();
```

See more info in Redisson docs: https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/8.-Distributed-locks-and-synchronizers